# Why I can't send data using submit button inside Form

Tags: javascript, .net-core, post

I want to create simple react component with form inside, every time that user click Submit button, data should be send to the server.

For testing purposes I created component with two buttons, one stand alone and one inside form.

```
return (
    <>
    <button onClick={submit}>Working example</button>
    <form style={cellStyle}
        onSubmit={submit}>
                
        <div>
            <input type="submit"
                value={reactDict["send"]}
                className="btn btn-success"
                style={{ margin: "15px 5px 5px 0px" }} />
        </div>
    </form>
    </>
);
```

Both of them use same "submit" function

```
const submit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ test: 'some message' })
    };

    fetch(`neededitems`, requestOptions)
        .then(async response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('There was an error!', error);
        });
}
```

When I click button outside form everything works fine [image: post form success],

When I click submit button inside form I got an error [image: post form error].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the attribute `method="post"` to the  element.

Comment: There was also a second problem, I have to add event.preventDefault(); to the submit function. I updated original post so that someone can use it later.

Comment: One more thing, if You are usingASP.NET Core CRA (Create React App) please check setupProxy.js file. You should add Your controller name there, otherwise You will always get 404.